# Jssor, iFrame, inline CSS and Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, iframe, jssor

I am using Jssor in my project to display an image gallery. I started working with one of the examples provided with Jssor download - image-gallery-source.html (jquery version). I was able to remove all the inline CSS and put in an externalized CSS file. Everything works fine when it is viewed as an independent page. However, when I try and load this page in an iFrame, I start getting CSS errors e.g.

```
20:53:27.882 Error: Width of slides container wrong specification, it should be specified in pixel (like style='width: 600px;').1 frontend.js:17689:14
```

When I launch the file outside the iframe it works fine. I am failing to understand what is causing this.
I tested it Safari and Chrome - it works like a charm. However, fails with all the errors in Firefox. If convert the style to inline, it starts complaining about other elements missing inline CSS.

Edit: Also tested in firefox developer edition and Opera - Works in Opera but fails in FireFox again. I could see the properties being set when I "inspect" the element but I see "NaN" being returned by the Javascript code when it tries to retrieve width etc.. I'm beginning to feel its a firefox quirk?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include external css in following manner,

```
<link href="external.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is a demo http://www.jssor.com/testcase/slider-in-iframe.html

Comment: Well..you've got inline CSS for almost all elements defining width, height, position etc. In fact, your external.css has little CSS. How about removing the inline css completely? I do not have any inline CSS and all css resides in external css file.

Comment: It's the same. You can move all to external css.